# UISearchDisplayController result table position issue in iOS7

Tags: ios7, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

Trying to implement UISearchBar into UINavigationBar my result tableview position become wrong (pic 2):

[image: Initial view]
[image: Search result view]

I've spent a couple of days to solve this issue, but there is no success )

Thanks!

**EDITED**

In my viewDidLoad:

```
[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setPlaceholder:NSLocalizedString(@"SEARCH_PLACEHOLDER", nil)];
[self.searchDisplayController setDisplaysSearchBarInNavigationBar:YES];
```

My SearchDisplayController Delegate methods:

```
-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
     //filter work repfectly
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
     [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                           scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                  objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

     return YES;
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"not (isFav == 100)"];

    [_fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPredicate:resultPredicate];
    [self performFetch];
}
```